# asp.net binding user control attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have method that I am using to check the access of certain controls.  For some reason, when I put breakpoints in the HasAcess method, I only see hit it once, where I am using it several areas in the page.  Any Ideas. I feel really dumb asking this question. It seems to be very obvious.

**ASPX Page:**

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIncludeVersions" runat="server" Text="Search Versions" Visible='<%# TR.Utility.HasAccess("ugEpisodeVersionsView")%>' />
```

**Code Behind:**

```
        public static Boolean HasAccess( string access)
    { // Breakpoint
        string userGroup = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroup"] as string;
        List<string> groupsAccess =  new List<string>( ((string)Settings.Default.Properties[access].DefaultValue).Split(','));

        return groupsAccess.Contains(userGroup);
    }
```

Comment: try to add trace.WriteLine("something") into your HasAccess method, do not trust the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: Is this a web site project, or a web application project?

Comment: Web site.  It doesnt look like it hits that method.  Very Strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it was something very stupid.  all I had to do is add Page.DataBind(); in the code behind.